# how can I cache get_or_create tuple - django

Tags: django, django-cache

how can I cache the `obj` (not the `created`)

```
obj, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(id=someid)
```

I cannot do:

```
cached_tuple = cache.set('cachekey', obj, created, 600)
```

any ideas?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here. I can't try this right now unfortunately, but have you considered trying to cache both values as a tuple?

Comment: Why would you want to cache the tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the `created` boolean cached? You can cache both separately:

```
cache.set('cachekey_obj', obj, 600)
cache.set('cachekey_created', created, 600)
```

But I'm not sure what you'd want with that. You could also try:

```
tpl = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(id=someid)
cache.set('cachekey', tpl, 600)
```

and then this should work, but I haven't checked right now:

```
obj, created = cache.get('cachekey')
```